# Why function doesn't pass to component's props when I use useNavigate

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I use useNavigate hook in react-router-dom 6, I pass props to child component in such way: `navigate('/pass', {state: {}})`. It works, but when I try to pass a function into state like `const example = () => console.log('example') ... navigate('/pass', {state: {func: example}})`
state is null
Why is it happens?

Comment: It's not immediately clear why (*haven't dug that deep*) but if you try the same thing using RRDv5 you actually see a run time error: `DataCloneError - Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': () => console.log("example") could not be cloned.` I suspect the issue/cause is the same in RRDv6 and it is swallowing the error. I'm guessing the function isn't serializable and thus can't be sent in route state. What is the use case you are trying to solve for here with sending functions in route state? I'm sure there are better alternatives.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Suddenly stopped working and realized that it was because a function was added to the props. Removed the function and worked.